# Google Places Autocomplete API key not working on live form & shiny (but works on jsfiddle)

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, google-maps-api-3, shiny

I am trying  to make an html form through google script and have a place field which requires autocomplete api. I tried the same using shiny app and I am getting similar errors.

The code works when tried in jsfiddle but the same when run through live google script url/ shiny app results in an error. "Oops something went wrong".

The error when checked on console is :
"Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError"

However I have placed no restrictions on the api key (to just make it work atleast once).

[API Key Config Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfLQb.png)

I have also enabled billing in the project. (But still obviously plan to run the project on the free credits I have :D)

I have followed the format of code as shown in this tutorial to build the form. https://www.bpwebs.com/how-to-create-data-entry-form-with-google-html-service-and-submit-data-to-google-sheets/ And customized the form to suit my fields.

Any suggestions on what to try out to make it work on the google script url or shiny?

There is unfortunately no google cloud support available to basic users and hence looking for the community to help out here.

Example Code:

```
    <!-- source: https://github.com/jamiewilson/form-to-google-sheets-->
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=EnterKEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
    <form name="tutorial-check">
      <div class="form-row"> 
      <label for="locationTextField">Select Eatery:</label>
      <input id="locationTextField" type="text" size="50" name = "eateryname">
      
      <script>
      function init() {
      var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
      }
      
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
      </script>
      </div> 
      <br>
      
      <label for="rating">Choose Rating: </label>
      <div class="form-row" col-md-6> 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='0'> 0: 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='1'> 1: 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='2'> 2: 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='3'> 3: 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='4'> 4: 
      <input type='radio' name='rating' value='5'> 5: 
      <br>
      </div>
     
      <div class="form-row"> 
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the author.

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Added. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many weeks of struggles around the api issue, I finally figured the problem and was able to resolve the issue. Posting it for everyone else who might be facing issues due to a similar problem.

So apparently there are different rules for Google Maps platform in India. The google cloud billing account cannot be used for Google Maps Platform usage. And it doesn't error out on the console for us to know that the issue of api's not being able to be used is because of lack of additional billing account to be put for maps apis.

https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq

So what needs to be done is, if your project includes only maps apis like mine, then you can disable the existing billing account from the project, set up a new one for maps project and link it with the project.

That should resolve the error of "Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError".

Maybe this is the not the case for other countries but wherever these new sets of rules are, this is a new additional thing to take care of.